# How can login authentication work with more than one ng-app

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

We have created one application with two html page and two ng-app one for admin and one for user side. I wanted single login authentication to work on both. Is that possible in AngularJS?

I have used toekn authentication with owin. http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/09/angularjs-token-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/comment-page-4/#comment-140050

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It does work. Refer below links:

[AngularJS Multiple ng-app within a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571301/angularjs-multiple-ng-app-within-a-page)

[Multiplw ngApp within a Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34725602/how-multiple-ng-app-works-in-angular)

And,
for the services, you can create **Factory by following MVC pattern and inject the service in the dependency injection** for your module or controller.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I said I have two html page one for admin side and another for users side and both have the ng-app separate and I want to add login authentication, will login work?

Comment: Yes. It will. Just you need to inject Services or factory that you are using properly.

Comment: I don't want both in single page as there are lots of different views will load on those both the pages.

Comment: Yeah. You could do that. Create a separate page with separate ng-app. The in app.js or whatever you're naming it, inject a module for both HTML templates in that file. That'll solve your query.